# use get_declared_class() to only ouput that classes I declared not the ones PHP does automatically

Tags: php

A little curious, but I want to make an array out of the classes that I have declared using something like this

```
foreach(get_declared_classes() as $class)
    $c[] = $class;


print_r($c);
```

the only problem with that is that I get something like on top of my loaded classes:

```
stdClass
Exception
ErrorException
Closure
DateTime
DateTimeZone
DateInterval
DatePeriod
LibXMLError
LogicException
BadFunctionCallException
BadMethodCallException
DomainException
InvalidArgumentException
LengthException
OutOfRangeException
RuntimeException
OutOfBoundsException
OverflowException
RangeException
UnderflowException
UnexpectedValueException
RecursiveIteratorIterator
IteratorIterator
{...}
SQLiteResult
SQLiteUnbuffered
SQLiteException
SQLite3
SQLite3Stmt
SQLite3Result
XMLReader
XMLWriter
XSLTProcessor
ZipArchive
```

is there a function that only loads user specific classes rather than system loaded classes? or perhaps a condition statement that limits the `foreach` to list those classes?

Comment: FWIW: Your loop is doing the exact same thing as a simple `print_r(get_declared_classes())`. Doesn't answer your question, but simplifies the code.

Comment: @eli, see my answer. It provides a solution that does not imply global variables and does not affect the performance. You probably should update the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46126712/1050262

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution that actually works and down't affect the performance.
This gives you only the classes defined in your project, nothing else. 
Make sure to run it as late as you can, after all classes were loaded.

```
/**
 * Get all classes from a project.
 *
 * Return an array containing all classes defined in a project.
 *
 * @param string $project_path
 * @return array
 */
function smk_get_classes_from_project( $project_path ){
    // Placeholder for final output
    $classes = array();

    // Get all classes
    $dc = get_declared_classes();

    // Loop
    foreach ($dc as $class) {
        $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($class);

        // Get the path to the file where is defined this class.
        $filename = $reflect->getFileName();

        // Only user defined classes, exclude internal or classes added by PHP extensions.
        if( ! $reflect->isInternal() ){

            // Replace backslash with forward slash.
            $filename = str_replace(array('\\'), array('/'), $filename);
            $project_path = str_replace(array('\\'), array('/'), $project_path);

            // Remove the last slash. 
            // If last slash is present, some classes from root will not be included.
            // Probably there's an explication for this. I don't know...
            $project_path = rtrim( $project_path, '/' );

            // Add the class only if it is defined in `$project_path` dir.
            if( stripos( $filename, $project_path ) !== false ){
                $classes[] = $class;
            }

        }
    }

    return $classes;    
}
```

**Test it.**

This example assumes that the project has this path: `/srv/users/apps/my-project-name`

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( smk_get_classes_from_project( '/srv/users/apps/my-project-name' ) );
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 19):

The Reflection API can detect whether a class is internal or not. [`ReflectionClass::isInternal`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isinternal.php) Checks whether the class is internal, as opposed to user-defined:

```
$userDefinedClasses = array_filter(
    get_declared_classes(),
    function($className) {
        return !call_user_func(
            array(new ReflectionClass($className), 'isInternal')
        );
    }
);
```

The code above will check and remove each class returned by `get_declared_classes` that is internal, leaving only the user defined classes. This way, you dont need to create and maintain an array of internal classes as was suggested elsewhere on this page.

Comment: in that context what is the `$className` variable?

Comment: @s2xi `get_declared_classes` returns an array of classnames. `array_filter` will pass each of these classnames to the anonymous function (the `$className`) and remove those from the array for which the anonymous function returns `false`. The anonymous function will create a new ReflectionClass instance for that classname and return the result of `ReflectionClass::isInternal` (a boolean). The `!` negates the result because we only want to allow classes that are not internal.

Comment: @s2xi check the alternate version I linked. might be easier to understand.

Comment: @Gordon Great solution. How about if one want it to also find both classes and traits that has been autoloaded?

Answer (score 13):

There is no built-in function to achieve this, but you can `get_declared_classes` just before you declare anything and store it in global variable, say `$predefinedClasses`. Then, where you need use:

```
print_r(array_diff(get_declared_classes(), $predefinedClasses));
```

Answer (score 5):

theres no directly built-in possibility for this, but you can do the following:

1. at the very start of your script, call `get_declared_classes()` and savve it to a variable like `$php_classes`
2. after loading your classes, call `get_declared_classes()` again and use [`array_diff()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to filter out the `$php_classes` - the result is a list of your own classes.

   ```
   // start
   $php_classes = get_declared_classes();

   // ...
   // some code loading/declaring own classes
   // ...

   // later
   $my_classes = array_diff(get_declared_classes(), $php_classes);
   ```

Comment: can i use it in a global scope within a construct?

Comment: $GLOBALS['php_classes'] would fit

Comment: thanks, i was going to ask how to use a global variable in the constuct =)

Answer (score 0):

One other possible way of doing is:

```
$a= get_declared_classes();

// All user-defined classes

print_r(array_slice(get_declared_classes(), count($a)));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon's answer is pretty good and 
@Dmitry's solution is also good but it works only if your classes were in different files and you included them:

```
$predefinedClasses = get_declared_classes();

include('Myclass.php'); // This will show
class A {} // This will not show
print_r(array_diff(get_declared_classes(), $predefinedClasses));
```

However, if you have classes in your file beside the ones you included and if you don't want to use `Reflection` there's a (crazy) idea I came up with:

```
$predefined_classes = get_declared_classes();

declare(ticks=1) {
    include 'Myclass.php';
    class A {}
    print_r(array_diff(get_declared_classes(), $predefined_classes));

}
```